# I Can't Resolve the R.java file!! Help?

Tags: android, dictionary, manifest, program-entry-point

I just want to generate a Google Maps app to play with Android development but I can't seem to get past this "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error.

I have tried the uncheck Build Automatically, Refresh, and Clean in many different orders, I have gone through hundreds of dicussions and tried to troubleshoot that way but I still can't resolve the error. :(

There is no R.java file generated in gen folder. The folder is empty.

I created the project with Eclipse by created a new project file with Google Maps API.

Here is my Manifest
AndroidManifest.xml (located in src):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aa.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AAappActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
</manifest>
```

My main.xml (located in res/layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:padding="12px" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:padding="12px" />
    <Button
        android:id="@_id/sat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Satellite"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:padding="8px" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/street"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Street"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:padding="8px" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/traffic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Traffic"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:padding="8px" />
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="my_Key" />
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml (located in res/values):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, AAappActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">AAapp</string>
</resources>
```

AAapp.java (located in src/aa.app):

```
package aa.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class AAappActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I get an R can't be found, it is usually due to an error in one of my Layout files.  When that happens, it breaks the autogenerator of the R file and when you build clean it removes the old R. file and then you are stuck.

Do any of your layout files show an error?

Edit:

And this is probably your error:

```
<Button
    android:id="@_id/sat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Satellite"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler"
    android:padding="8px" />
```

That should be:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Satellite"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler"
    android:padding="8px" />
```

Comment: Good catch on the underscore. I fixed that, cleaned, rebuilt... still getting the error and no R.java file.